# How many is “a multitude” of heavenly hosts in Luke 2:13

Tags: greek, word-study, luke

**Luke 2:13 (ESV)**

> And suddenly there was with the angel a ***multitude*** of the heavenly host praising God and saying

I’ve heard some teach that this is translated from “murias” (Strong's 3461), which means "tens of thousands".

The Greek word I have come up with is “plethos” (Strong's 4128), which is defined as:

1. a great number, of men or things
2. the whole number, the whole multitude, the assemblage, the multitude of the people.

I would appreciate anything that might shed further light on this matter?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clue:-

> NWT Daniel 7:9, 10  "“I kept watching until thrones were set in place and the Ancient of Days sat down. His clothing was white like snow, and the hair of his head was like clean wool. His throne was flames of fire; its wheels were a burning fire. 10 A stream of fire was flowing and going out from before him. **A thousand thousands kept ministering to him, and ten thousand times ten thousand stood before him.** The Court took its seat, and books were opened.
>
> NWT Revelation 5:11  "And I saw, and I heard a voice of many angels around the throne and the living creatures and the elders, and **the number of them was *myriads of myriads* and thousands of thousands, ..."**

A "myriad" is innumerable, so we could be talking of millions of millions?

Comment: Good answer +1.

Comment: Thanks! The word myriads was what I had heard in a lesson. The problem is that in Luke 2:13, “a multitude” translates to the word “plethos” in the Greek, which means “a multitude”. I’m puzzled because Luke is not known for being shy on details.

Answer (score 0):

Another clue: "For unto which of the angels said he at any time, Thou art my Son, this day have I begotten thee? And again, I will be to him a Father, and he shall be to me a Son? And again, when he bringeth in the firstbegotten into the world, he saith, And let all the angels of God worship him."
(Heb 1:5-6)
God's only begotten was worthy of ALL angels to attend the day of his birth.  The shepherds saw a multitude, they saw all they could see, but all of the heavenly host were in attendance to worship the newborn King. (Rev 5.11 states at least 100M angels exist.)

Answer (score 0):

May I share an answer with you? Do you know how many hairs are on your head! Of course not!  The Holy inspired Scriptures say that our great and mighty God knows the number of the very hairs on your head! Since he does and we don’t! I am sure this is very clear he knows how many angels he created before his complete creation in the beginning however we don’t! The conclusion is there is no number given in the Holy Scriptures! The Greeks came up with the highest number at that time 10,000 times 10,000! With our great and mighty God, the number is off the chart that man has come up with! Myriads, multitudes, and on, and on! No one knows but God our Creator! In his great grace, love, and mercy my personal Lord and Savior Jesus Christ! Amen!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).